# How to make these struct functions generic?

Tags: c#, generics, struct

I have these two functions which read a stream into a buffer and loads it into the given struct.

```
    TestStruct1 ReadRecFromStream2(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestStruct1))];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, 128);
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            return (TestStruct1)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(TestStruct1));
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }

    TestStruct2 ReadRecFromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestStruct2))];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, 128);
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            return (TestStruct2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(TestStruct2));
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
```

I'd like to combine these into a generic function to take either of the structs, I'm just unsure what the proper way to do this is.

Is this the correct way?

```
    private T ReadRecFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, HeaderSize);
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this seems pretty ok code,

Comment: Okay, thank you. Someone told me in person that the generic version I made was wrong, but didn't offer any insight on why/how it was wrong. Figured I'd ask here. thanks!

Comment: Probably you should pass the `HeaderSize` as a parameter... Unless it is fixed for all the T.

Comment: Woops, that's a remnant of a previous function. Yeah it's a fixed size, all 128. Going to make that a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use these methods to convert from and to byte[]:

```
public static unsafe byte[] ToBytes<T>(this T value)
    where T : struct
{
    var result = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
    fixed (byte* b = &result[0])
    {
        var p = new IntPtr(b);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, p, false);
    }

    return result;
}

public static unsafe T FromBytes<T>(this byte[] bytes, int startIndex = 0)
    where T : struct
{
    fixed (byte* b = &bytes[startIndex])
    {
        var p = new IntPtr(b);
        return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Using this your methods could be changed to:

```
T ReadRecFromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    where T : struct
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    return buffer.FromBytes<T>()
}
```

Read would work similar.

Comment: I like this, thanks. I just realized though, my structs have different number of fields, so would I have to pass in the type of struct somewhere as well? Since my original two functions were of type `that struct`.

Comment: @pfinferno I don't get the problem. You can pass any struct you like to these methods. You don't need to register the meta information of how the struct is defined. The generic contains all data needed to create the correct buffer. Maybe I missunderstand you. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm confused on how to pass the structure to the method? For instance, let's say I make a `TestStruct2` called `test`. Right now I do `test = ReadRecFromStream(stream)`, since `ReadRecFromStream` is of type `TestStruct2`. But with the generic function that isn't happening? I might just be stupidly confusing myself.

Comment: Nevermind! Yeah I was just confusing myself, it works fine. Thanks!